# Twice click to get language

Tags: php

when i click the 'Arabic' button, the page text language not work, but if i reload the same page, it work and change to Arabic.
My `conflang.php`:

```
<?php
$allowed_lang = array('en', 'ar');
if(isset($_GET['lang']) === true && in_array($_GET['lang'], $allowed_lang) === true){
 setcookie('lang', $_GET['lang'], time() + 31556926, "/", null, null, true);
}else if(isset($_COOKIE['lang']) === false){
   setcookie('lang', 'en', time() + 31556926, "/", null, null, true);  
}

if(isset($_COOKIE['lang'])){
include 'lang/' . $_COOKIE['lang'] . '.php';
}else{
    include 'lang/en.php';
}
?>
```

and my `index.php`:

```
<?php  if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] === 'en') : ?>
<a href="?lang=ar">Arabic</a>
<?php endif ?>

<?php  if (isset($_COOKIE['lang']) && $_COOKIE['lang'] === 'ar') : ?>
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>
<?php endif ?>

<?php  if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) : ?>
<a href="?lang=en">English</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: change `GET` to `POST`

Comment: @Aso how is possible?

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> Once the cookies have been set, they can be accessed on **the next page load** with the $_COOKIE array.

Comment: how to fix that please?

Comment: There are many possible ways.  Easiest thing would be to simply issue a refresh with the query parameter removed after you set the cookie.  Another way would be to set the cookie via ajax when the button is clicked.  A third option might be to use session variable in conjunction with cookies.  It all really depends on your app.